# Why does a Java program require a "main()" method?

Tags: java, entry-point

It is just a naming convention? Why can't any method be called while executing a program from a shell e.g

```
$> java myPackage.MyClass.myOwnEntryPoint(String[] str)
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's a naming convention, inherited from C. The advantage is that this way, it's very simple to find out which method is supposed to be the main method just by looking at the code.

Comment: No *just* a convention, though, is it? I mean, when you run the program (via `java`), that's what it looks for...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Yes, that's true. But you could write your own program launcher, which loads a class and run method `myPersonalMain()` instead. That's why it's "only a convention" - though an important one that many tools (not just `java`) use.

Comment: @T.J.: well, there's different kinds of code convetions. Breaking some will just irritate other programmers, while others have to be followed for the code to work at all. Another example for the latter are the naming convetions for setters and getters.

Comment: I see what you're saying. For me, if it's hardcoded into an absolutely central tool like `java`, that's not a *convention*, it's a requirement. :-) But @sleske has a good point: You could write your own program launcher that used a different name.

Answer (score 1):

The `main` method is the entry point that the `java` program for running Java applications (as opposed to applets or other things) looks for. As far as I'm aware, there's no way to tell `java` to look for a different method instead, so it's not just a naming convention; if you want your application to run (via the standard `java` tool, anyway), you want to give it a `main` method with the appropriate signature. (You can play games with static initializers, but that's another thing entirely.)

The name `main` is inherited from C, but it's not just a convention.